# Visual representations of the p-value in ANOVA to assist intuitive understanding

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, data-visualization

I'm a statistics newbie and I would like to make sense of the p-value with ANOVA, hopefully with a visual presentation. All online visual tools I've found so far only have MSB, MSE and F values visually presented (such as [this here](http://www.psych.utah.edu/aoce/tools/Anova/anovatool.html). I'm a very visual person and I would like to see how it works before I learn more about it.

Do you have any suggestions for me? It could be a Matlab program as well, something where I play with the distributions and see the p value change.

Comment: The p-value is often less interesting than effect size or MSB/MSE, notwithstanding the fact that it is associated to a null hypothesis of the form $H_0:\;\mu_0=\mu_1=\dots=\mu_k$ (vs. $H_1:\;\exists\, i,j\mid \mu_i\neq\mu_j$) which makes the global test uninteresting if you don't look at the between-group differences.

Comment: @chl In the situation of a two-sample t-test, it is often recommended that a confidence interval for the difference in means be given, regardless of whether the test is significant. If the ANOVA F-test is non-significant, would it be a good idea to give the Tukey HSD confidence intervals for differences in means?

Comment: @mark999 Right. However, showing the bootstrap or asymptotic precision of an estimate is different from a single p-value in a NHST context, whatever the result of the test is, IMO. Moreover, if the overall ANOVA test is not significant, it is usually not recommended to go further with post-hoc (especially Tukey HSD which are framed in an ANOVA context). I was just suggesting that the ANOVA F-test says nothing about where the difference really lie, hence the need to look at the observed differences.

Comment: @chl Thanks for your reply. The usual recommendation you mentioned is the reason I asked. But for a two-sample t-test, giving a confidence interval is recommended to show that even with a high p-value, the 95% CI may still contain large values in both directions, so it would be a mistake to conclude that the non-significant p-value means there is no difference. What is the analogous procedure in one-way ANOVA? Is there anything really wrong with giving the Tukey HSD intervals when the F test is non-significant, to show that large differences may be plausible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a toy example for simulating a one-way ANOVA in R.

First, I just defined a general function that expect an effect size (`es`), which is simply the ratio MSB/MSW (between/within mean squares), a value for the MSB, the number of groups, which might or not be of equal sizes:

```
sim.exp <- function(es=0.25, msb=10, groups=5, n=NULL, verbose=FALSE) {
  msw <- msb/es
  N <- ifelse(is.null(n), sample(10:40, groups), groups*n)
  means <- rnorm(n=groups, mean=0, sd=sqrt(msb)) 
  my.df <- data.frame(grp=gl(groups, 1, N), 
                      y=rnorm(N, means, sqrt(msw))) 
  aov.res <- aov(y ~ grp, my.df)
  if (verbose) print(summary(aov.res))
  ave <- with(my.df, tapply(y, grp, function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x))))
  invisible(list(ave=ave, p.value=summary(aov.res)[[1]][1,5]))
}
```

This function returns the p-value associated to the F-test, as well as the sample means and SDs. We can use it as follows:

```
> sim.exp(verbose=TRUE)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
grp          4  32.71   8.176  0.1875 0.9418
Residuals   18 784.93  43.607               
> sim.exp(es=2, verbose=TRUE)
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
grp          4 555.66 138.915  33.567 1.653e-09 ***
Residuals   24  99.32   4.138                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 
> sim.exp(es=.5, n=30, groups=3, verbose=TRUE)
            Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)    
grp          2  639.12  319.56  16.498 8.42e-07 ***
Residuals   87 1685.13   19.37                     
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Then, I created a grid of values for `es` and `msb`, that is I want to check whether varying these parameters has an effect on the estimated p-value.

```
my.design <- expand.grid(es=seq(.2, 2.4, by=.2), msb=seq(2, 10, by=2))
n.sim <- nrow(my.design)
```

Finally, let's use it. First, with a single replicate of each condition:

```
for (i in 1:n.sim)
  my.design$p[i] <- sim.exp(my.design[i,1], my.design[i,2], n=20)$p.value
```

As can be seen, when increasing the effect size we are more likely to reject the null (averaged over MSB):

```
> with(my.design, aggregate(p, list(es=es), mean))
    es            x
1  0.2 1.178042e-01
2  0.4 1.315028e-02
3  0.6 5.765548e-02
4  0.8 5.742882e-02
5  1.0 8.940993e-05
6  1.2 9.199611e-09
7  1.4 9.115640e-06
8  1.6 8.100427e-10
9  1.8 2.656848e-07
10 2.0 3.577391e-05
11 2.2 5.477981e-14
12 2.4 1.219156e-04
```

The results are shown below, although for clarity I took the log of the p-value. The horizontal dashed line shows the 5% limit for type I risk.

[image]

Ok, it's somewhat noisy. So, let's try to average p-values for 500 replicates in each conditions:

```
for (i in 1:n.sim)
  my.design$p[i] <- mean(unlist(replicate(500, 
                      sim.exp(my.design[i,1], my.design[i,2], n=20))[2,]))
```

and the results are:

[image]

We can play with `es` only as follows:

```
k <- 10000
es1 <- sample(seq(.1, 5, by=.1), k, rep=T)
pp <- numeric(k)
for (i in 1:k) 
  pp[i] <- sim.exp(groups=3, es=es1[i])$p.value
plot(es1, -log10(pp), pch=19, col="#FF737350", cex=.6, xlab="Effect size (MSB=10)")
xx <- seq(.1, 5, by=.1)
lines(xx, predict(loess(-log10(pp) ~ es1), data.frame(es1=xx)), 
      col="green", lwd=2)
```

[image]

Many other experiments are possible, and probably a better code too.

Comment: Thank you so much for all this. I wish I knew how to read R. But what I'm understanding here is that you wrote a function that gives the p value for a given experiment with effect size, group size etc. Then you play with that function to see how the p value changes as the effect size changes. In the last graph you show how the p value gets smaller as the effect size goes larger. Did I understand correctly?

Comment: @gazialankus Yes, that's basically what the above code does. I hope you'll manage to customize it to answer your questions.

Comment: (+1) A minor thing: One might explicitly distinguish between the true effect size used for the simulation and its estimate. It seems your `es` is $f^{2} = (\frac{1}{J} \sum_{j} \alpha_{j}^{2}) / \sigma^{2}$ (groups $1, \ldots, J$, effect parameters $\alpha_{j} = \mu_{j} - \mu$, error variance $\sigma^{2}$, equal group sizes). I.e., your `msb` is the variance of the true $\mu_{j}$, and your `msw` is $\sigma^{2}$. The empirical sum of squares give the estimate $\hat{f}^{2} = MS_{b} / MS_{w}$, but your simulation uses the theoretical counterparts.

Comment: @caracal You're right. I used Cohen's f (and in fact, I should take the square of `es`...), following an example found on [R-help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/simulating-the-anova-td852030.html) a long ago that I just retrieved right now (I searched for it yesterday during 30'!). Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

There could possibly be a good reason why the MSB, MSE, and F values are only shown.  These are what is "actually important" in the analysis so to speak.  A p-value is just a sampling probability of some function of these three quantities (not sure of the specific function).

You don't need a p-value if you understand how to interpret these quantities.  p-value doesn't provide you with "extra" information, and it is so easy to mis-interpret (such as: probability for hypothesis, probability of eroneous conclusion, probability of type 1 error, etc.).  It can be quite fun to have a "p-value bash" every now and then :)

Much more useful and informative to look at effect sizes.  For if they are all pretty close - to within say plus/minus one standard error - then you already know without any need for hypothesis testing, that the data do provide support in favour of the hypothesis of equal means $H_0:\;\mu_0=\mu_1=\dots=\mu_k$.  You only need a hypothesis test, in the formal setting when it isn't "obvious" whether or not to accept or reject.  Say if one or two out of 20 means were between 2 and 3 standard errors away from the rest.  This is when the hypothesis test will help.  And also, if you see 10 out of the 20 groups over 3 standard errors apart, then you don't need the test: you know the null is not supported by the data.

Comment: That's great insight, thank you. So, in the latter case where we have 10 out of 20 over 3 standard errors apart, what would you do to formally say that null is not supported? I'm guessing in a paper you would want to do the home run in that case and point it out formally. Would you say, look, we have a large effect size? What's the definition of "large" in that case?

Comment: I wouldn't think you would need to say anything "formally" in addition to the F ratio, then followed by something like "there is no need for a formal test".  I would instead focus on the hypothesis that are supported by the data.  And my "formal" method would be to report the posterior probability that the null hypothesis is true.  An alternative would be to report the likelihood ratio, that is $\frac{Pr(Data|H_0)}{Pr(Data|H_{max})}$.  Once again, there is no need for a p-value of the Likelihood ratio - it already tells you how much the data support the null